# grep, поиск в нескольких файлах

Tags: grep

имею дамп .sql на 17 Гб ~ 70 файлов разного текстового содержания, нужно выдернуть всю строку содержащую 1 из 200 e-mail адресов

для примера:

```
1@mail.ru
2@yandex.ru
3@rambler.ru
4@gmail.com
```

Делаю grep -wi -e (w для точного поиска по слову) '1@mail.ru' * (* для поиска по всем файлам в папке, аналог ключа -r) Находит

А делаю так:

```
grep -wi -e '1@mail.ru|2@yandex.ru|3@rambler.ru|4@gmail.com' *
```

Не находит ни одного

что не так делаю?

Comment: может вот так? grep -wi -e '1@mail.ru && 2@yandex.ru && 3@rambler.ru && 4@gmail.com' * или вместо && поставить
 - так ничего не нашлось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -wi '1@mail.ru\|2@yandex.ru\|3@rambler.ru\|4@gmail.com' *
```

Comment: а можно ли уменьшить количество левака?
при grep -wi '1@mail.ru\|2@yandex.ru\|3@rambler.ru\|4@gmail.com' *
находятся как 1@mail.ru так и 111111@mail.ru

Comment: @user2061175 хм... по идее -w и должно было решить это. Но если нет, то попробуйте сделать так: `\b1@mail.ru\b` вместо `1@mail.ru`

Comment: тоже самое что и с -w, может как то с -x можно?

Comment: @user2061175 в каких-то случаях можно, но сейчас это выглядит как `методы научного тыка`. Давайте таки пару строк реального файла (емэйлы можно заменить), которые появляются в поиске по шаблону 1@mail.ru, т.е. одну строку  соответствующую шаблону, а вторую, которая "лишняя".